# Matlab - random forest classifier 10fold-cross validation accuracy

Tags: matlab, classification, random-forest, cross-validation

I have a dataset of 20000 instances with 4421 features. For scientific reasons ( publication), I need to perform a 10 fold-cross validation from this dataset as the individual and average accuracy of the classifier using random forest with Matlab. Please, could you tell me have to perform 10 cv from my dataset and obtaining the classification accuracy?

Here my code so far:

```
data = load ('HCTSA_N.mat');

% This makes sure we get the same results every time we run the code.
rng default

traindata = data.TS_DataMat;
trainlabels = {data.TimeSeries.Keywords};


% How many trees do you want in the forest? 
nTrees = 20;

% Train the TreeBagger (Decision Forest).
B = TreeBagger(nTrees,traindata,trainlabels, 'Method', 'classification');
```

Comment: not sur to understand the question,... 1) split your data into k samples 2) train k times your data over k-1 samples 3) calculate the mean square error (or whatever you need) for each iteration

Comment: where I get the mean square error from the model generated?